# Problems with AJAX inside PHP while loop

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, while-loop

I'm using PHP WHILE loop to display many products (each has an id#) as a HTML list and each product can be rated. The rating system is PHP AJAX JQUERY based. When js is implemented after a user rates the product and AJAX returns the value, the value is being displayed in that product item and then ALL the product items following. I would like it to display in only the product item that was rated. Is there any special considerations for using AJAX within a loop in missing here?

No errors in browser tools or on page I can see. I've moved the js file around the loop in many positions and this is the best configuration I've come up with.

A lot of code I know but if any of the tags are involved I thought it important to show that.

html start loop

```
    <div id="main" role="main">
      <ul>
        <?php       
    while  . . .
    ?>
        <li>
          <div id="products">
            <div data-storyidr="
    <?php echo $id; ?>" class="rateit"> </div>
            <div id="response<?php echo $id; ?>"> </div>
          </div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
```

js

```
    <script type ="text/javascript">
      $('#products .rateit').bind('rated reset', function (e) {
        var ri = $(this);
        var value = ri.rateit('value');
        var storyidr = ri.data('storyidr');
        ri.rateit('readonly', true);
            $.ajax({
            url: 'rate.php',
            data: { storyidr: storyidr, value: value }, 
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
             $('#response<?php echo $id; ?>').append(data);
            },
            error: function (jxhr, msg, err) {
             $('#response<?php echo $id; ?>').append('<li style="color:red">' + msg + '</li>');
                      }
              });
      });
    </script>
```

end loop

```
          </li>
        <?php
    endwhile;
    mysqli_close($connection);
    ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: You will have multiple `<script type ="text/javascript">`. What exactly is the problem ? Are you getting any exceptions/errors?

Comment: Sorry, the value is displaying in multiple products within the loop, not just the single product item  which was rated. Editing original question with this.

Comment: No errors in browser tools or on page I can see. I've moved the js file around the loop in many positions and this is the best configuration I've come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that you're binding a function to every `#products .rateit` element on the page over and over again with that PHP loop. You should really just bind **once**, and use the data that you already have stored on each element to carry out your javascript logic. Since `storyidr` is set to be the same as the `$id` in PHP, why don't you just use that?

The following code should be *outside* the PHP loop.

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
  $('#products .rateit').bind('rated reset', function (e) {
    var ri = $(this);
    var value = ri.rateit('value');
    var storyidr = ri.data('storyidr');
    ri.rateit('readonly', true);
        $.ajax({
        url: 'rate.php',
        data: { storyidr: storyidr, value: value }, 
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
         $('#response'+storyidr).append(data);
        },
        error: function (jxhr, msg, err) {
         $('#response'+storyidr).append('<li style="color:red">' + msg + '</li>');
                  }
          });
  });
</script>
```